# Unify MFC messages and Qt signals-slots/events

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, signals, win32gui

I've got an assignment to create sort of a multi-platform C++ GUI library. It wraps different GUI frameworks on different platforms. The library itself provides an interface via which the user communicates uniformly (using the same code) regardless of the platform he's using - typically it's MFC on Windows and Qt elsewhere.

Currently, I'm stuck on messages/events. So far, I've been using MFC messages and Qt signals to get notified of the user's interaction and had no problems with that. The user creates a list box (which contains `p_lb` - pointer subclassed `QListWidget` on Qt or `CListBox` on MFC) and then he ties his own `DoSomething()` handler with an event.

User's code:

```
ListBox lb;
lb.AddDoubleClickHandler([](int i) { DoSomething(i); });
```

This is what it looks like in the library:

```
// p_lb represents platform list box - QListWidget/CListBox
// handler's int parameter represents the index of the item, that has been double-clicked
    void ListBox::AddDoubleClickHandler(const std::function<void(int)>& handler) {
#ifdef _MFC_PLATFORM
        // only pushes the handler into the internal list
        p_lb->double_click_handlers_.push_back(handler);
#elif _QT_PLATFORM
        p_lb->connect(p_lb, &QListWidget::itemDoubleClicked, p_lb,
                [handler, p_lb](QListWidgetItem* item) { handler(p_lb->row(item)); });
#endif
    }
```

In MFC I need to call the handlers stored in the list manually:

```
#ifdef _MFC_PLATFORM
class MyMFCListBox : public CListBox {
public:
    std::list<std::function<void(int)>> double_click_handlers_;

    afx_msg void OnItemDoubleClick() {
        for (const auto& h : double_click_handlers_) {
            h(GetCaretIndex()); // call user's stored handler when the event occurs
        }
    }

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

};
    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyMFCListBox, CListBox)
        ON_CONTROL_REFLECT(LBN_DBLCLK, &MyMFCListBox::OnItemDoubleClick)
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()
#endif // _MFC_PLATFORM
```

As I said, this works fine, but now I need to be able to notify UI control about some external event manually (and asynchronously) - using something like MFC's [PostMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea). The use case would be something like updating progress bar based on some external computing (which is not necessarily done using this library). E.g. I'm uploading some photos, after each one of them I send a message to the ProgressBar about the current number of uploaded photos and number of all the photos, but I return immediately without waiting for the handler to execute. Also, there needs to be a way of adding new custom events by the user. I know that Qt has a similar method - [postEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent), but is this the right way to implement it? Or should I implement my own signal-slot system? I cannot imagine how this would work. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You can give up on Qt. It's unfixably broken when it comes to window messages. [Replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121206-00/?p=5903) outlines, what can go wrong, when you attempt to record and replay messages. Qt does just that, dumping your only chance to ever see the full picture. Some of the things that won't work with Qt: `GetMessageExtraInfo` no longer returns that data. `GetMessageTime` returns a value that doesn't relate to the message being handled. `WM_TOUCH`'s associated data is lost. The list goes on and on...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but "giving up" is not an option, it's an assignment I got. The best option for me would be to use events in Qt, but there's no such event like "list box item double-clicked" or "slider dragged" like in MFC - I would need to create them myself and that seems like a hell of an error-prone stuff to do, so I guess I gotta stick to the signals-slots. But how would I provide this asynchronous event/message/signal sending mechanism?

Comment: This isn't going to happen. MFC controls are backed by `HWND`s. Qt uses a happy mixture, where some controls are, but most aren't. MFC wires up its message routing statically, Qt does it at runtime. MFC's runtime reflection is based on `CObject`, which needs to be the ultimate base class. Qt uses `QObject`, which needs to be the base class. Either one is incompatible with each other, and a class cannot have both as their base. MFC uses Windows' message routing, Qt tried to invent its own (and failed, miserably). You aren't going to unify those differences. Qt gave up a decade ago.

Comment: In the ListBox above, I don't want it to inherit from `CObject` nor `QObject`. ListBox contains `p_lb` pointer, which on MFC is `MyMFCListBox` inheriting from `CListBox` and on Qt, it's `MyQtListBox` inheriting from `QListWidget`. At least one of the handler invoking mechanisms (sending message/generating event/emitting signal...) and then returning the control right back to the caller without waiting for the handler to be executed exists on both platforms (in MFC it's PostMessage and in Qt it's `QCoreApplication::postEvent` or `emit` with `Qt::QueuedConnection`. So there has to be a way.

Comment: There are lots of ways fumbling something together that sort of works, sometimes. But realistically, you cannot hope to do this. Qt gave up a decade ago on their Qt/MFC Migration Framework, that attempted to do this. Now those were the makers of Qt. If they cannot do it, what makes you think that you could? You'd need to be intimately familiar with Qt, MFC, and the Windows API. And once you are, you'll see that Qt is a lost case. That *may* change with Qt version 6, but I won't hold my breath.

Comment: In no way I think I'm capable of doing that, that's why I asked for help. I believe you and the solution that "sort of works" would be enough for me, I guess. Anyway, thank you for your time, again I learned something new:) I will try to somehow make it work making a wrapper for MFC's `PostMessage` and Qt's `postEvent` (even though `postEvent` may have a different behavior in some cases) because again - I have no way of avoiding this problem.

Comment: The answer to your question can *easily* fill an entire book. You are wildly underestimating the complexity of the task. Much like the makers of Qt. Your implementation would not only have to deal with the intricacies of MFC and the Windows API. It would also have to undo all the effects of Qt that were implemented due to assumptions about the operating system that were flat out wrong. Good luck with that task. Denial will only prolong your suffering. And eventually disappoint any client of your code.

Comment: I believe you, but the denial is not coming from me and I can assure you, the decision is completely out of my hands.